# Treegrid with JSON data in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am testing trees in jqgrid, so far I am only able to create something like below

[image]

I want to have something like [jqGrid Demo page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

I came up with the below code, but no idea how should I go about expanding each row in the tree from the given json format

```
$('<table id="list2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table></div>').appendTo('#topics');

var grid = jQuery("#list2");
grid.jqGrid({
    datastr:topicjson,
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    height: "auto",
    pager: false,
    loadui: "disable",
    colNames: ["id","Items","url"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "id",width:1,hidden:true, key:true},
        {name: "elementName", width:150, resizable: false},
        {name: "url",width:1,hidden:true}
    ],
    treeGrid: true,

    caption: "jqGrid Demos",
    ExpandColumn: "elementName",
    autowidth: true,
    //width: 180,
    rowNum: 200,
    //ExpandColClick: true,
    treeIcons: {leaf:'ui-icon-document-b'},
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "response"
    }
});
```

Json format

```
var topicjson={
    "response": [
                 {
                     "id": "1",
                     "elementName": "Grouping",
                     "sub": [
                         {
                             "subelementName": "Simple Grouping"
                         },
                         {
                             "subelementName": "May be some other grouping"
                         }
                     ]
                 },
                 {
                     "id": "2",
                     "elementName": "CustomFormater",
                     "sub": [
                         {
                             "subelementName": "Image Formatter"
                         },
                         {
                             "subelementName": "Anchor Formatter"
                         }
                     ]
                 }
             ]
         };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You try to use Tree Grid with absolutely wrong formatted data. You should see tree grid as a grid with some additional hidden columns which defines the tree structure. The names of the columns depends on the value of the `treeGridModel` parameter. I recommend you to use `treeGridModel: "adjacency"`. In the case the names of the hidden columns will be:

```
level, parent, isLeaf, expanded, loaded, icon
```

In case of treeGridModel: 'nested' there are `lft` and `rgt` instead of `parent` column.

Because every item of the tree (root nodes and all subitems) represents grid's row which will be placed in the grid every item have to have id. In your original version of the `topicjson` variable the you defined ids only for the root elements (elements of the level 0).

We can modify your original example to the following:

```
var topicjson={
    "response": [
           {
               "id": "1",
               "elementName": "Grouping",
               level:"0", parent:"", isLeaf:false, expanded:false, loaded:true
           },
           {
               "id": "1_1",
               "elementName": "Simple Grouping",
               level:"1", parent:"1", isLeaf:true, expanded:false, loaded:true
           },
           {
               "id": "1_2",
               "elementName": "May be some other grouping",
               level:"1", parent:"1", isLeaf:true, expanded:false, loaded:true
           },
           {
               "id": "2",
               "elementName": "CustomFormater",
               level:"0", parent:"", isLeaf:false, expanded:true, loaded:true
           },
           {
               "id": "2_1",
               "elementName": "Image Formatter",
               level:"1", parent:"2", isLeaf:true, expanded:false, loaded:true
           },
           {
               "id": "2_1",
               "elementName": "Anchor Formatter",
               level:"1", parent:"2", isLeaf:true, expanded:false, loaded:true
           }
       ]
    },
    grid;

$('<table id="list2"></table>').appendTo('#topics');

grid = jQuery("#list2");
grid.jqGrid({
    datastr: topicjson,
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    height: "auto",
    loadui: "disable",
    colNames: [/*"id",*/"Items","url"],
    colModel: [
        //{name: "id",width:1, hidden:true, key:true},
        {name: "elementName", width:250, resizable: false},
        {name: "url",width:1,hidden:true}
    ],
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: "adjacency",
    caption: "jqGrid Demos",
    ExpandColumn: "elementName",
    //autowidth: true,
    rowNum: 10000,
    //ExpandColClick: true,
    treeIcons: {leaf:'ui-icon-document-b'},
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: "response"
    }
});
```

You can see the results of the modification on the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AdjacencyTreeRicky.htm):

[image]

In the example I set `expanded:true` property for the `CustomFormater` node to demonstrate that you can specify which nodes should be directly displayed expanded.

I removed hidden column `id` from the tree grid because the id will be saved additionally as the `id` attribute of the corresponding `<td>` element. If you don't plan to make the column visible I would recommend to place the `id` property only in the input data of the tree (in `topicjson`).

One more important remark. All grid rows will be filled in exactly the same order in which they are in the input data. So you have to place the child nodes of the node immediately after its parent. I placed the corresponding [change request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/reordering-of-tree-grid-items-on-expanding-or-sorting-on-filling/#p23926) in the trirand forum. So probably the requirement about the strict order of the input data for the tree grid will be changed somewhere later.

**UPDATED**: To have sorting work correctly one have to use `parent:null` or `parent:"null"` instead of `parent:""` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) for more details.

Comment: Oleg, if my json data structure is already nested (Just a rough example, "results1":[{"testKey":testValue,"testKey2":testValue, "testKey3":[{"ListKey":"ListValue"},{"ListLey2":ListValue}]}), is it possible to construct a tree grid with it?  Or does the json has to be necessarily in the flat form with pointed parent, and level?

Comment: @DimaR.: If you examine exactly TreeGrid you will see that all rows of TreeGrid have **the same columns**. So TreeGrid is just Grid where there are exist parent->child relation between rows. The items which you posed have **absolutely different properties**. I am not sure how you want display such data. Probably [Grid with Subgrids](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) is more close to what you need.

Comment: Thank you !! (belated, but still)

Comment: @DimaR.: You are welcome! I'm glad that my old answers still be helpful. Be carefully, the old answer contains small error : the value of root element `parent:""` (see `"id": "1"`) should be `parent:"null"` or `parent:null`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) for details.

Comment: you should know that in the absence of a coherent documentation on the subject, your posts here serve as a perfect text book.  At lest, I found it this way ..