# jqGrid getRootNodes method is returning empty array

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid getRootNodes method  is returning empty array, I'm using the following code to get the root nodes

```
var records = $trackerGrid.jqGrid("getRootNodes");
console.log(records);
```

any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you filled `parent` property of the root nodes in the wrong way. It should be `parent: "null"` or `parent: null` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935)).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree13.htm) create tree grid having tree root nodes. One from the nodes is leaf. The demo shows that `getRootNodes` works correctly.