# JQGrid - Load at Once not loading in a correct order

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

I am using JQGrid version 4.1.2. With this I am facing some problems in tree grid while using Adjacency model (Load at once). I Am loading the JSON data from a server. Tree grid is getting formed according to the row order from JSON data. Say for ex: I am forming tree grid for Branch & Department. In my query I am not able to sort according to the parent child hierarchy, because around 6 tables I need to join. But I can get the records with proper id, parent, level & is_leaf properties.

What the grid is doing means - just its creating the rows from JSON whatever order it is. So the tree format is not coming up properly. When I click the root node of any department, it's collapsing the correct child but all children are under different parent(according to my JSON order).

Below is the data which I am getting as a JSON from my server.

```
id     name               level      parent     is_leaf     expanded     loaded
—–    —————–—–            —–—–—–    —–—–—–—–    —–—–—–—–   —–—–—–—–—–   —–—–—–—–—–
B1     Shanghai Pvt Ltd     1        (null)     false       true         true
D3     Finance & Account    2         B1         true        true         true
D4     Production           2         B1         true        true         true
D5     Support              2         B1         true        true         true
D6     Operation            2         B1         false       true         true
D13    Software             2         B1         true        true         true
D82    BPO                  2         B1         false       true         true
D76    Sub D12              3         D1         true        true         true
D75    Sub D11              3         D1         true        true         true
D78    Sub D21              3         D2         false       true         true
D84    Operation1           3         D6         true        true         true
D83    BPO1                 3         D82        false       true         true
D79    Sub D211             4         D78        false       true         true
D87    BPO11                4         D83        true        true         true
D80    Sub D2111            5         D79        true        true         true
D1     Admin                2         B1         false       true         true
D2     Sales                2         B1         false       true         true
B13    Beijing Pvt Ltd      1         (null)     false       true         true
D86    Test 2               2         B13        false       true         true
D134   Test Root            2         B13        true        true         true
D91    Test Level 1         3         D85        false       true         true
D93    Test 2 Level 1       3         D86        true        true         true
D133   Test Level 3         5         D92        true        true         true
D92    Test Level 2         4         D91        false       true         true
D85    Test                 2         B13        false       true         true
B14    Branch Office 3      1         (null)     false       true         true
D132   Software             2         B14        false       true         true
D95    Level 1              3         D132       true        true         true
D94    Root                 2         B14        true        true         true
D136   Level 2              3         D132       true        true         true
B15    Branch Office 4      1         (null)     true        true         true
```

Inside jqgrid function I've defined all of these.

```
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel:'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn : 'deptName'
```

Is there anything I am missing/doing wrong, or this is how tree grid works right now?

Answer (score 1):

When using TreeGrid the json data needs to be sorted in the way it will be displayed.

All the child nodes need to be under the parent in the json data. This is a limitation of TreeGrid.

In my opinion, the tree should render based on the associations already defined in the data being returned from the server

Answer (score 0):

I have never implemented treeGrid in jqgrid, but i'll advise you to check these references

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree8.htm

see the example on http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html > New in 3.4 > Tree grid Adjacency Model

and this answer [Sorting of jqGrid (v4.1.2) treegrid not working with Ajacency Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330572/sorting-of-jqgrid-v4-1-2-treegrid-not-working-with-ajacency-model)
 from Oleg.