# JqGrid Sorting data when tree grid and json binding is done

Tags: json, jqgrid

Is it possible in JqGrid to do sorting when it is a tree grid with adjacent model and data is bind using json!! I want to sort data on different column and it is not a tree column.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't posted details. So I have to guess. Typical problem with sorting of TreeGrid is wrong filling of `parent` field of the root elements of the tree. The value should be `null` or `"null"` and not `""` for example. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) for details.

Comment: @Deepesh: You should post more details (code, test JSON response from the server) about what you do. Like you can see from the referenced answer (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree8.htm) for example) the sorting is do possible. So the problem is either in the code which you use or in the JSON data. So to help you to find the error you should provide more details.