# jqGrid treegrid populated with local data - jsonmap not working

Tags: jqgrid

I am loading a treegrid using local data. For some reason, jqGrid is displaying cell values based on "name" property and not "jsonmap" property of the colModel.

Here is a simplified version of the grid and the local data. With the below configuration, I get empty values in the "Qty" column. However, if in "mydata" I change "qty1" to "qty" I get values in the "Qty" column.

```
var mydata =  {"rows":[
    {id: 1221,name: "P1",qty1: "1", level: 0,parent: "NULL",isLeaf: false, loaded: true, expanded: true},
    {id: 1222,name: "P1-Child",qty1: "2", level: 1,parent: 1221,isLeaf: true, loaded: true, expanded: true}
]};

jQuery("#bomTable").jqGrid({
       treeGrid:true,
       treeGridModel:'adjacency',
       ExpandColumn:'name',
       treedatatype: "local",
       datatype: "local",
       data: mydata,
       jsonReader: {
           repeatitems: false
       },
       colNames:['ID', 'Name', 'Qty'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'id', hidden: true},
           {name:'name', index:'name'},
           {name: 'qty', jsonmap: 'qty1', index: 'qty'}
       ],
       width:'auto',
       height:'auto',
       shrinkToFit:false
   });

   jQuery("#bomTable")[0].addJSONData({
       total: 1,
       page: 1,
       records: mydata.rows.length,
       rows: mydata.rows
   }) ;
```

Would greatly appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use `datatype: "local"` and `jsonmap` will be not used in the case (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.base.js#L1038-L1040) of jqGrid code).

I recommend you to use `datatype: "jsonstring"` instead (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7332627/315935) for the code example).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jsonmapInTreeGrid1.htm) provides the fixed version of your code. It displays

[image]

It uses the code

```js
var mydata = {"rows": [
    {id: 1221, name: "P1",       qty1: "1", level: 0, parent: "NULL", isLeaf: false, loaded: true, expanded: true},
    {id: 1222, name: "P1-Child", qty1: "2", level: 1, parent: 1221,   isLeaf: true,  loaded: true, expanded: true}
]};

$("#bomTable").jqGrid({
     treeGrid: true,
     treeGridModel: "adjacency",
     ExpandColumn: "name",
     treedatatype: "local",
     datatype: "jsonstring",
     datastr: mydata,
     jsonReader: {
         repeatitems: false
     },
     colNames: ["Name", "Qty"],
     colModel: [
         {name: "name"},
         {name: "qty", jsonmap: "qty1"}
     ],
     height: "auto",
     sortname: "name",
     shrinkToFit: false,
     autoencode: true,
     gridview: true
 });
```