# Page 1 of 0 even if jqgrid contains data

Tags: javascript, free-jqgrid

I am using addRowData to append the data to grid in ajax call.It displays the data correctly but on pagination it shows Page 1 0f 0 which is incorrect.

I have added rowNum:10 in jqgrid table property.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'getData',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
                $('#grid').jqGrid('clearGridData');
                for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++){
                                $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, data[i]);
                            }
                $('#grid').setGridParam({rowNum:$('#grid').getGridParam('rowNum')});   

                }
        });
```

Jqgrid table is -

```
$("#grid").jqGrid(
                {
                    width : 'auto',
                    height : 'auto',
                    colNames : [ 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
                    colModel : [ {
                        name : "firstName",
                        index : "firstName",
                        key:true,
                        width : 120,                                                    
                        search : true,
                        stype : "text"
                    }, {
                        name : "lastName",
                        index : "lastName",
                        width : 120,                                                    
                        search : true,
                        stype : "text"
                    },
                    multiselect : false,
                    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    datatype : "local", 
                    loadonce : true,                            
                    rowNum : 10,        
                    rowList : [ 10, 20, 30, 100000000 ],
                    loadtext : '', 
                    loadui : 'disable',
                    toppager:true,
                    pager : '#prowed2',
                    viewrecords : true,
                    loadComplete : function() {
                        $("option[value=100000000]").text('All');
                    },
                    gridComplete : function() {
                    }

                });
```

I expect data to be shown and pagination should display Page 1 of 1

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never fill `addRowData` in the loop to fill the grid. jqGrid, which has `datatype: "local"` supports `data` parameter for creating the grid and filling it with data. Seconds, it you want to display all the data at one page (which is bad idea in case of large number of rows) then you can use `rowNum` to large enough value, for example, 1000, which will be interpreted as maximum of rows, which will be displayed on the page.

To replace full data in existing grid you can replace `data` and trigger `reloadGrid` event. To replace the data I'd recommend to use `getGridParam` instead of usage `setGridParam`. The method `getGridParam` without parameters returns *the reference* to all internal grid parameters. So to replace `data` parameters you need to change the `data` property of the internal grid parameter object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getData',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var $grid = $("#grid"),
            p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to all parameters

        p.data = data; // replace data parameter
        $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", { page: 1 }); // display new data in the grid
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried the solution given by you but still it is not working.Now I am not even able to see the data in the grid.It showa Page 1 0f 0 with no data.Please suggest

Comment: @Stack_User: You should post more information about the grid, which you create. For example, if you use TreeGrid, then you should follow [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935507/315935), which uses `populate` method instead of `reloadGrid`. In general, you should always include information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (or can use) and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Your code, which creates jqGrid and test data are important too.

Comment: I have edited my ans provided jqgrid table defination.I am using  free jqgrid.Here I am not using tree jqgrid its a simple jqgrid table

Comment: @Stack_User: You made an error in your tests. You can verify on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/xegtnq2u/ that the approach, which I described in my answer works. Click on "Set 1" or "Set 2" buttons to reload the data in the grid.