# jqGrid TreeGrid problems

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Can anyone explain to my what I may be doing wrong please?

I have the following code:

```js
function initTable() {


mydata = [{ "id": "1", "brandName": "7 Crown With Honey", "quality": "Standard", "minorRegionName": "North America", "year00": "", "year01": "", "level": "0", "parent": "", "isLeaf": "false", "expanded": "false" },
            { "id": "2", "brandName": "Amaretto di Florio", "quality": "Standard", "minorRegionName": "North West Europe", "year00": "", "year01": "", "level": "1", "parent": "1", "isLeaf": "true", "expanded": "false" },
            { "id": "3", "brandName": "Aniversario Rum", "quality": "Super Premium", "minorRegionName": "South America", "year00": "5", "year01": "6", "level": "1", "parent": "1", "isLeaf": "true", "expanded": "false" },
            { "id": "4", "brandName": "Archers", "quality": "Standard", "minorRegionName": "Asia", "year00": "2", "year01": "1", "level": "0", "parent": "", "isLeaf": "false", "expanded": "false" }
         ];

$("#list2").jqGrid({
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn: 'brandName',

            data: mydata,
            datatype: 'local',
            height: 300,

            colNames: ['brandName', 'minorRegionName','quality', 'year00', 'year01'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'brandName', index: 'brandName', width: 200 },
                                { name: 'minorRegionName', index: 'minorRegionName', width: 200 },
                                { name: 'quality', index: 'quality', width: 100},
                                { name: 'year00', index: 'year00', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", formatter: "number" },
                                 { name: 'year01', index: 'year01', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", formatter: "number"}],

        rowNum: 30,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'brandName',
        pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
        });


    $("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    //$("#list2").setGridParam({ datatype: 'local', page: 1, rowNum: 20 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
```

Which, quite simply, doesn't produce a TreeGrid with nested rows.

I know the data is working fine, because if I comment out:

```js
treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn: 'brandName',
```

Sure enough the data displays.

I'm pretty sure it's something obvious, but can't see what it is.

Comment: Are you sure that the word ExpandColumn is camel cased well? Shouldn't you write the first letter of it lowercase?

Comment: Thought that myself to be honest, have tried both methods and still not working though. (the 'ExpandColumn' was copied direct from the jqGrid website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that TreeGrid don't support `datatype: "local"`. So you have to add the data manually with respect of `addJSONData` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333199/315935)) or use `datatype: "jsonstring"`, `datastr: mydata` and additional `jsonReader` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782262/315935)).

Your demo can be modified for example to [the following demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jasonmhirst.htm).

Comment: Oleg, perfectly easy to understand answer, thank you so much. And glad to see your example confirms the "ExpandColumn" too, just so I (others?) know for the record.  Again my thanks for such an understandable answer.

Comment: @JasonMHirst: You are welcome! jqGrid seems be developed without clear name conversion. So there are options like `ExpandColumn`, `datatype` and `colNames` instead of common style or names like `expandColumn`, `dataType` and `colNames` for example. If you use jqGrid you have to follow the existing names.